# ServiceStack working but Swagger-UI not

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I have followed the ServiceStack (3.9.37) tutorials and have created an empty ASP.Net Web Application and have the webservice working as expected here:

`http://www.somedomain.com:53032/api/metadata`

I have also linked in Swagger-UI Package (3.9.35)

I have added  Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature()); in AppHost.Configure

My problem is that the Swagger-UI is not available as I would expect here:

`http://www.somedomain.com:53032/swagger-ui/index.html`

I get error "Handler for Request not found: " with a stack trace.

I have tried target framework 4.0 and 4.5 with same result. Visual Studio Version is 2012

Anything I have missed to get this linking in correctly ?

Answer (score 3):

Worked out that it was a path issue. Resolved by following modifications to web.config:

```
//Added Location node
//path moved here
<location path="api">  // Path moved to location area !!!

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime/>
<httpHandlers>

//Path returned to wildcard
<add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>

</httpHandlers>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
<add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```